# Round date to first day of next month

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

The following query takes `application_date` and gives the last day of the month of application (`cohort`), and the Sunday of the week of application (`first_week`):

```
select 
cast(last_day(application_date) as date) end as cohort,
cast(dateadd(day, -(datepart(dow, application_date)), application_date) as date) first_week
from table
```

This works perfectly for what I am trying to do, however in cases where month of `cohort` <> month of `first_week`, then I would like to round `first_week` to the first day of the next month (= `cohort` month).

Current output example:

```
application_date   cohort   first week
1/2/18             1/31/18  1/31/17
1/5/18             1/31/18  1/31/17
1/7/18             1/31/18  1/7/18
1/13/18            1/31/18  1/7/18
2/1/18             2/28/18  1/28/18
```

Expected output:

```
application_date   cohort   first week
1/2/18             1/31/18  1/1/18
1/5/18             1/31/18  1/1/18
1/7/18             1/31/18  1/7/18
1/13/18            1/31/18  1/7/18
2/1/18             2/28/18  2/1/18
```

Thank you!

Comment: what if the first week is `12/30/2017`?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu this can't happen. `first_week` can be 12/31/2017 or 12/24/2017 or 1/7/2017, etc. but not 12/30/2017 because definition of `first_week` is the Sunday of the week of the `application_date`. If you mean what if `application_date` is 12/30/2017 then `first_week` would be 12/24/2017 and this doesnt require adjustment.

Comment: I suggests show more examples for better understanding

Comment: @maSTAShuFu sure, updated

Comment: why is 1/7/18 first week is 1/7 and also 1/13?.. can you please include the logic behind the first week.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu if `application_date` is 1/7/18, then `first_week` is Sunday of week of 1/7/18, which is 1/7/18 and if `application_date` is 1/13/18, then `first_week` is still 1/7/18 because that is the date for Sunday that week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Case Statement` logic read as

1) If the last sunday is of the previous month then get the 1st day of the application date and this is your first week. 
2) If the application date is not a sunday then get the sunday date before the application date which is not from the previous month.

```
declare @mytable table (application_date date,cohort date)
insert into @mytable
values
('1/2/18','1/31/18'),  -- 1/1/18
('1/5/18','1/31/18'),  -- 1/1/18
('1/7/18','1/31/18'), -- 1/7/18
('1/13/18','1/31/18'), -- 1/7/18
('2/1/18','2/28/18'),  -- 2/1/18   
('2/27/18','2/28/18')  -- 2/25/18   


select *,

case when 
        month(
         case when datepart(dw,application_date)=1 then  application_date
         else dateadd(day,(-1*datepart(dw,application_date))+1,application_date)
         end

   ) <> month(application_date) then
      cast(concat(year(application_date),right('0' + cast(month(application_date) as varchar(20)),2),'01') as date)
    else
       case when datepart(dw,application_date)=1 then 
              application_date
       else 
           dateadd(day,(-1*datepart(dw,application_date))+1,application_date)
       end
   end     firstweek

from @mytable
```

Comment: @ma unfortunately this is not Redshift proper syntax so can't use.

Comment: just need to translate it... IIF is similar to case.

Comment: @user8834780 now using `Case Statement`

Comment: You have to translate it

Comment: @ma I got it to work, but unfortunately it is giving incorrect output. While `week_end` is right for 1/1/2018-1/6/2018, `application_date` of 12/31/2017 gives `week_end` of 12/1/2017, and for the rest `application_date` is the Monday (instead of Sunday) of the week of application.

Comment: what's the `application date` and `cohort` on that?

Comment: I actually managed to alter your query to make it work- so all good thank you!